# Fiona Saving Gives DriverIOError

Tags: python, shapely, fiona, pandas

I have a script that I used before to clip polygons. I modified it a touch to use in another place, but am running into a `fiona.errors.DriverIOError`. As far as I can tell, all the code is working until I get the to saving section. Is there something that I am missing?

```
import pandas
import fiona
from shapely.geometry import Polygon, mapping
from osgeo import osr

srs = osr.SpatialReference()
srs.SetFromUserInput("EPSG:3857")
wgs84 = srs.ExportToWkt()


VerificationPlots = fiona.open('E:/99/verification/99Buffer.shp')

for EachBigBuffer in VerificationPlots:
    BigBuffer = Polygon(EachBigBuffer['geometry']['coordinates'][0])


    i = 0

    ManualList = []
    ManualProperties = []
    ManualShape = fiona.open("E:/99/verification/99PointBuffer.shp")
    for EachManualVerification in ManualShape:
        ManualVerification = Polygon(EachManualVerification['geometry']['coordinates'][0])

        ManualList.append(ManualVerification)
        ManualProperties.append(EachManualVerification['properties'])

    clipPolyList = []
    clipPolyProperties = []
    for index, poly in enumerate(ManualList):
        result = BigBuffer.intersection(poly)
        if result.area:
            clipPolyList.append(result)
            clipPolyProperties.append(ManualProperties[index])
    print("BigBuffer: ", BigBuffer)
    print("ManualVerification: ", ManualVerification)
    print("clipPolyList: ", clipPolyList)

    schema = ManualShape.schema
    outFile = fiona.open('D:\\Random\\LB\\test' + str(i) + '.shp',
                         mode='w', driver='ESRI Shapefile', crs=wgs84, schema=schema)

    for index, poly in enumerate(clipPolyList):
        outFile.write({
            'geometry': mapping(poly),
            'properties': clipPolyProperties[index]
        })

        i = i + 1

    outFile.close()
```

output:

```
C:\Users\anaconda3\envs\random\python.exe D:/Random/Verification.py
BigBuffer:  POLYGON ((-13724564.99436397 5513756.697011174, -13724565.36731331 5513754.342301677, -13724566.44965447 5513752.218087551, -13724568.13544035 5513750.532301676, -13724570.25965447 5513749.44996052, -13724572.61436397 5513749.077011174, -13724574.96907347 5513749.44996052, -13724577.09328759 5513750.532301676, -13724578.77907347 5513752.218087551, -13724579.86141462 5513754.342301677, -13724580.23436397 5513756.697011174, -13724579.86141462 5513759.05172067, -13724578.77907347 5513761.175934796, -13724577.09328759 5513762.861720671, -13724574.96907347 5513763.944061828, -13724572.61436397 5513764.317011174, -13724570.25965447 5513763.944061828, -13724568.13544035 5513762.861720671, -13724566.44965447 5513761.175934796, -13724565.36731331 5513759.05172067, -13724564.99436397 5513756.697011174))
ManualVerification:  POLYGON ((-13724322.52290537 5513216.387490636, -13724322.53036436 5513216.340396446, -13724322.55201118 5513216.297912164, -13724322.5857269 5513216.264196446, -13724322.62821118 5513216.242549622, -13724322.67530537 5513216.235090636, -13724322.72239956 5513216.242549622, -13724322.76488384 5513216.264196446, -13724322.79859956 5513216.297912164, -13724322.82024638 5513216.340396446, -13724322.82770537 5513216.387490636, -13724322.82024638 5513216.434584825, -13724322.79859956 5513216.477069108, -13724322.76488384 5513216.510784825, -13724322.72239956 5513216.532431649, -13724322.67530537 5513216.539890636, -13724322.62821118 5513216.532431649, -13724322.5857269 5513216.510784825, -13724322.55201118 5513216.477069108, -13724322.53036436 5513216.434584825, -13724322.52290537 5513216.387490636))
clipPolyList:  [<shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon object at 0x0000018F5231C0C8>, <shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon object at 0x0000018F5231C5C8>, <shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon object at 0x0000018F5231C548>, <shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon object at 0x0000018F5231C608>, <shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon object at 0x0000018F5231C648>, <shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon object at 0x0000018F5231C788>, <shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon object at 0x0000018F5231C688>, <shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon object at 0x0000018F5231C748>, <shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon object at 0x0000018F5231C7C8>, <shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon object at 0x0000018F5231C848>, <shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon object at 0x0000018F5231C708>, <shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon object at 0x0000018F5231C6C8>, <shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon object at 0x0000018F5231C888>, <shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon object at 0x0000018F5231C808>, <shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon object at 0x0000018F5231C8C8>, <shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon object at 0x0000018F5231C908>, <shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon object at 0x0000018F5231C948>, <shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon object at 0x0000018F5231C988>, <shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon object at 0x0000018F5231C9C8>, <shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon object at 0x0000018F5231CA08>, <shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon object at 0x0000018F5231CA48>, <shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon object at 0x0000018F5231CA88>, <shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon object at 0x0000018F5231CAC8>, <shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon object at 0x0000018F5231CB08>, <shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon object at 0x0000018F5231CB48>, <shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon object at 0x0000018F5231CB88>, <shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon object at 0x0000018F5231CBC8>, <shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon object at 0x0000018F5231CC08>, <shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon object at 0x0000018F5231CC48>, <shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon object at 0x0000018F5231CC88>, <shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon object at 0x0000018F5231CCC8>, <shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon object at 0x0000018F5231CD08>, <shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon object at 0x0000018F5231CD48>, <shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon object at 0x0000018F5231CD88>, <shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon object at 0x0000018F5231CDC8>, <shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon object at 0x0000018F5231CE08>, <shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon object at 0x0000018F5231CE48>, <shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon object at 0x0000018F5231CE88>, <shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon object at 0x0000018F5231CEC8>, <shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon object at 0x0000018F5231CF08>, <shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon object at 0x0000018F5231CF48>, <shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon object at 0x0000018F5231CF88>, <shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon object at 0x0000018F5231CFC8>, <shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon object at 0x0000018F52322088>, <shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon object at 0x0000018F52322048>]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "fiona/ogrext.pyx", line 1133, in fiona.ogrext.WritingSession.start
  File "fiona/_err.pyx", line 291, in fiona._err.exc_wrap_pointer
fiona._err.CPLE_AppDefinedError: Failed to create file D:\Random\LB\test0.shp: No such file or directory

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Random/Verification.py", line 63, in <module>
    mode='w', driver='ESRI Shapefile', crs=wgs84, schema=schema)
  File "C:\Users\anaconda3\envs\random\lib\site-packages\fiona\env.py", line 417, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\anaconda3\envs\random\lib\site-packages\fiona\__init__.py", line 274, in open
    **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\anaconda3\envs\random\lib\site-packages\fiona\collection.py", line 165, in __init__
    self.session.start(self, **kwargs)
  File "fiona/ogrext.pyx", line 1141, in fiona.ogrext.WritingSession.start
fiona.errors.DriverIOError: Failed to create file D:\\Random\LB\test0.shp: No such file or directory
```

**Update - Working Code**

```
srs = osr.SpatialReference()
srs.SetFromUserInput("EPSG:3857")
wgs84 = srs.ExportToWkt()

VerificationPlots = fiona.open('E:/99/verification/99Buffer.shp')

i = 0
for EachBigBuffer in VerificationPlots:
    BigBuffer = Polygon(EachBigBuffer['geometry']['coordinates'][0])

    ManualList = []
    ManualProperties = []
    ManualShape = fiona.open("E:/99/verification/99PointBuffer.shp")
    for EachManualVerification in ManualShape:
        ManualVerification = Polygon(EachManualVerification['geometry']['coordinates'][0])
        ManualList.append(ManualVerification)
        ManualProperties.append(EachManualVerification['properties'])

    clipPolyList = []
    clipPolyProperties = []
    for PolyIndex, poly in enumerate(ManualList):
        result = BigBuffer.intersection(poly)
        if result.area:
            clipPolyList.append(result)
            clipPolyProperties.append(ManualProperties[PolyIndex])

    schema = ManualShape.schema
    outFile = fiona.open('D:/Random/LB/test' + str(i) + '.shp',
                         mode='w', driver='ESRI Shapefile', crs=wgs84, schema=schema)

    for index, poly in enumerate(clipPolyList):
        outFile.write({
            'geometry': mapping(poly),
            'properties': clipPolyProperties[index]
        })
    outFile.close()

    i = i + 1
```

Comment: Your escaping looks off when building the output path.  You should use [raw strings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2081708/6179432) instead of double backslashes

Comment: I originally just had back slashes (`/`) and then I just changed to two forwards slashes to try it out. Using raw strings also gives the same error.

Comment: Make sure the path `D:\Random\LB` exists.

Comment: @user2856 Yes it does exist.

Comment: I ended up changing to a different directory and it worked. I changed back to the `D:/Random/LB` and it worked. The only thing I see different between my working one and non-working one is I changed the position of the `i` variable.